# Convert from PDF to Postscript Arabic font

Tags: postscript

I have a postScript file with some Arabic text, and GhostScript does not render the text correctly.

Any help is appreciated

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ghostscript are you using ? On what operating system ? What command line ? Do you get any feedback on the back channel ?

In what sense 'not rendered correctly'?

The title says 'convert from PDF to PostScript', yet you say you have PostScript file, so which is it ?

If you think you have a genuine problem you would be better to open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com. At the very least you need to supply the information above and make the source file available.

You really haven't supplied enough information for anyone to help you with whatever your problem is.